# Как разместить два textView горизонтально в ряд?

Tags: android

У меня в приложении есть список сообщений (вход./исход.) и мне нужно что-бы в этом списке каждый элемент состоял из даты прихода сообщения, темы и отправителя/получателя. У меня сейчас есть такой xml файл моей разметки списка RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

мне нужно сделать так что-бы textView с датой шло сразу за именем отправляющего/принимающего. Если кто знает где у меня ошибка буду очень благодарен если скажите как ее исправить))

Comment: Из `id` ваших `TextView` неясно, кто там отправляющий/принимающий. Объясните на примере `id` ваших `TextView`.

Comment: у меня в данном файле разметки textView с id from это отправляющий, у меня вообще один файл разметки и я в него просто разные данные вставляю при разных условиях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для размещения вью элементов в `LinearLayout` горизонтально, достаточно указать в нем горизонтальную ориентацию.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="cetner_vertical">

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```